# Is there a workaround for failing gcutil adddisk?

Tags: google-compute-engine, gcutil

The command line request to create a disk from a global image (generated via the web console) fails:

> gcutil --service_version="v1beta15" --project=<project-id> adddisk <boot-id> --size_gb="10" --zone="us-central1-b" --source_image="https://www.googleapis.com/compute/v1beta15/projects/debian-cloud/global/images/debian-7-wheezy-v20130816"
>
> ValueError: Invalid argument: https://www.googleapis.com/compute/v1beta15/projects/debian-cloud/global/images/debian-7-wheezy-v20130816

The same succeeds when run from the web console.  Is this a known issue?  Is there a workaround?  I am using gcutil version 1.8.4.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a regression in gcutil 1.8.4.  If you downgrade to 1.8.3, this command will work.